# PHP CURL does not return the full token

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I am using PHP curl to do basic Auth that return a jwt token.

When I Request the token in shell using curl i get a token of length 381 .However when I do the request in my php code i only get a token of length 326 which is not complete which lead to other problems in my other php requests .

how can i make my php code give me the full length of my token that is 381 in my response and not just 326?

Update my cURL shell code is :

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://xxxx/xxxx/auth/login' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic XXXXX'
```

my curl php code :

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://xxxxx/xxxxx/auth/login",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",   
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,   
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,   
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,   
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,  
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( "Authorization: Basic xxxxxxx" ),
) );

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl); echo $response;
```

Thanks

Comment: post the shell curl and the php code in your question

Comment: @Paolo just added code

Comment: at a first glance they looks like functionally identical. you may try `--enable-ascii debug-file.txt` on **curl** and `CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1` on **php curl** to dump the data exchange between client and server, compare them and spot differences. hope it helps..